# How to hide/dismiss image on Collpasing the CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, whatsapp, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am making a screen using CollapsingToolbarLayout in my app. Below is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightest_grey"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/myAppBar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="300dp"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

       <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
           android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
           android:background="@color/primaryColor"
           android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

           <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/ivCompanyLogo"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
           app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" >

           </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
       </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

<!-- Something other layout -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I run my app it shows me `CollapsingToolbarLayout` congaing screen with background image `ic_launcher`.

My problem is, when I scroll Up, I want to hide/dismiss the image. Currently it gets adjusted into Toolbar.

Reference is just like whatsapp's profile `CollapsingToolbarLayout` design.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Toolbar's  app:layout_collapseMode attr's value to pin.